# Difference between bootstrap row vs col-md-12

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I am new to bootstrap

Is  `row` and `col-md-12` both are same or different.?  if diff how.?

I don't see any changes in output, I may wrong.!

**With Row**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
       <p>Words go here</p>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Without Row:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
       <p>Words go here</p>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Check out the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options).. The row is to contain columns. Without it grid layouts will break for various reasons.

Comment: @ZimSystem thank you for the clean and simple answer.